# How can I specify multiple directories for RSpec to pull tests from?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have some vendored gems that are being developed in tandem with my project and i'd like to be tell rspec to run the tests for those gems as well as those for my main app. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

just put spaces in between the directories like:

```
rspec spec/model/location.rb ../gem/spec/requests/user.rb
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using rspec and all your spec files are ending in `_spec.rb` then you can simply define the Rails root directory:

```
rspec .
```

Depending on the size of your codebase, this may be slower but in my case it didn't make a difference and found all specs no matter in which directory they are, for example in `engines/*/spec`.